# C# How do I set a column in a multidimensional array with a switch statement?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, switch-statement

So in this class, I'm trying to use a switch statement to determine which radio button is checked in the form.

**This is the part of the code that I'm focused on**

```
private void lstTransactions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = lstTransactions.SelectedIndex;
            if (index != -1)
            {
                txtAmount.Text = entries[index, 0];
                txtDate.Text = entries[index, 1];
                chkCleared.Checked = bool.Parse(entries[index, 3]);
                // entries[index, 2] is transaction type
                //make switch comparison work correctly
                // to determine which radio button should be checked

                switch(entries[index, 2])
                {
                    case TransactionTypes.Deposit.ToString():
                        rbDeposit.Checked = true;
                        break;
                    case TransactionTypes.Withdrawal.ToString():
                        rbWithdrawal.Checked = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        rbServiceFee.Checked = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Typing `case TransactionTypes.Deposit.ToString():` and `case TransactionTypes.Withdrawal.ToString():` gives me an error that says "CS0150   A constant value is expected". I tried looking up the error and **I still can't figure out how to make the switch comparison work.**

**Here's the full Forms Code for Reference**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Transaction3
{
    public partial class CheckbookForm : Form
    {
        public CheckbookForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        enum TransactionTypes { Deposit, ServiceFee, Withdrawal }
        TransactionTypes transactionType;

        private string[,] entries = new string[20, 4];



        decimal balance = 0m;
        decimal bankBalance = 0m;

        private void SetError(Control whichControl, string message)
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(whichControl, message);
        }

        private decimal IsValid()
        {
            bool flag=true;
            decimal amount = 0m;

            DateTime date;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(txtDate.Text,out date))
            {
                if (date>DateTime.Today)
                {
                    flag=false;
                    SetError(txtDate,"Date must be on or before today");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                flag=false;
                SetError(txtDate,"Date must be entered");
            }

            if (decimal.TryParse(txtAmount.Text, out amount))
            {
                if (amount<=0)
                {
                    flag=false;
                    SetError(txtAmount,"Amount must be more than zero");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                flag = false;
                SetError(txtAmount,"Amount must be a number more than zero");
            }

            if (flag)
            {
                if (transactionType == TransactionTypes.Withdrawal)
                {
                    if (balance >= amount)
                    {
                        amount *= -1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        flag = false;
                        SetError(txtAmount, "Insufficient funds");
                    }
                }
                else if (transactionType == TransactionTypes.ServiceFee)
                    amount *= -1;
            }
            if (!flag)
                amount = 0;
            return amount;
        }

        private void ShowBalance()
        {
            lblBalance.Text = balance.ToString("c");
            lblBankBalance.Text = bankBalance.ToString("c");
        }

        private void ClearForm()
        {
            txtAmount.Clear();
            txtAmount.Focus();
            txtDate.Clear();
            rbWithdrawal.Checked = true;
        }

        private void CheckbookForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rbDeposit.Tag = TransactionTypes.Deposit;
            rbWithdrawal.Tag = TransactionTypes.Withdrawal;
            rbServiceFee.Tag = TransactionTypes.ServiceFee;
            ClearForm();
            ShowBalance();
        }

        private void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            errorProvider1.Clear();
            decimal amount = IsValid();
            if (amount != 0)
            {
                string entry;
                string process = "Not Processed";
                balance += amount;
                if (chkCleared.Checked)
                {
                    bankBalance += amount;
                    process = "Processed";
                }
                ShowBalance();
                int row = lstTransactions.Items.Count;
                entries[row, 0] = amount.ToString();
                entries[row, 1] = txtDate.Text;
                entries[row, 2] = transactionType.ToString();
                entries[row, 3] = chkCleared.Checked.ToString();

                entry = string.Format("{0} {1}: {2} ({3})", transactionType.ToString(),
                    txtDate.Text, amount.ToString("c"), process);
                lstTransactions.Items.Add(entry);
            }
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearForm();
        }

        private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            errorProvider1.Clear();
            DialogResult button;
            button = MessageBox.Show("Clear all prior entries and set balance to $0?\nThis CANNOT be undone.",
                "Reset Account", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (button == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)            {

                balance = 0;
                bankBalance = 0;
                ClearForm();
                ShowBalance();
                lstTransactions.Items.Clear();
            }
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void rb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;
            if (rb.Checked) 
                transactionType = (TransactionTypes) rb.Tag;
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnExit_Click(sender, e);
        }

        private void CheckbookForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult button;
            button = MessageBox.Show("Close and exit? All entries will be lost.",
                "Exit?", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question,
                 MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
            if (button == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel)
                e.Cancel = true;
        }

        private void lstTransactions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = lstTransactions.SelectedIndex;
            if (index != -1)
            {
                txtAmount.Text = entries[index, 0];
                txtDate.Text = entries[index, 1];
                chkCleared.Checked = bool.Parse(entries[index, 3]);
                // entries[index, 2] is transaction type
                //make switch comparison work correctly
                // to determine which radio button should be checked

                switch(entries[index, 2])
                {
                    case TransactionTypes.Deposit.ToString():
                        rbDeposit.Checked = true;
                        break;
                    case TransactionTypes.Withdrawal.ToString():
                        rbWithdrawal.Checked = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        rbServiceFee.Checked = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `ToString` in the case statement; instead, convert `entries[index, 2]` into a transaction type and then do the switch without `ToString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ditch the *multidimensional array* and go with a *typed* List or Array.

Multidimensional arrays are useful when the data is of the same type, yours it a bit of everything. so we in turn would make a class.

```
public class Entry
{
   public Entry(decimal amount, DateTime date, TransactionType transactionType, bool cleared)
   {
      Amount = amount;
      Date = date;
      TransactionType = transactionType;
      Cleared = cleared;
   }

   public decimal Amount { get; set; }
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   public TransactionType TransactionType { get; set; }
   public bool Cleared { get; set; }

}
```

**Given**

```
// now an array of Entry
private Entry[] entries = new Entry[20];
```

**Usage**

To update update an entry

```
// add / update and array slot
entries[row] = new Entry(amount, DateTime.Parse(txtDate),transactionType,chkCleared.Checked);
```

Your switch would look like this

```
switch (entries[index].TransactionType)
{
   case TransactionTypes.Deposit:
      rbDeposit.Checked = true;
      break;
   case TransactionTypes.Withdrawal:
      rbWithdrawal.Checked = true;
      break;
   default:
      rbServiceFee.Checked = true;
      break;
}
```

<sub>***Note*** : This is not meant to be a working example, or to make your code work, it was merely showing you how you could used a typed array to make your life easier and show a potential for the switch without having to parse your string back into an enum</sub>

Alternatively you could just use [`Enum.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=netframework-4.8)

> Converts the string representation of the name or numeric value of one
>   or more enumerated constants to an equivalent enumerated object.

```
var tranType = (TransactionTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(TransactionTypes), entries[index, 2]);
switch(tranType)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are facing, has nothing to do with multidimensional arrays. It is due to using a **runtime** value inside a case logic.

You cannot use `case TransactionTypes.Withdrawal.ToString()` as a case statement. The last part `ToString()` is a function call. Even though it will always return the same value, the compiler does not know that. It will always think that the value of `case TransactionTypes.Withdrawal.ToString()` is not known at **compile time**, and thus is a potential risk for **runtime** error and thus will not compile.

You might wanna think what is the harm in having a **runtime** value. Consider the following code -

```
switch (entries[index].TransactionType)
{
   case TransactionTypes.Withdrawal.ToString()://only known at wexecution not before that
      throw a;
      break;
   case TransactionTypes.Withdrawal.ToString()://only known at wexecution not before that
      throw b;
      break;
   default:
      break;
}
```

Both the cases have same values. But the compiler cannot determine them unless it executes the code and when it will try to do that, there will be a clash in the decision. To save the code for such failure, having dynamic value in a `switch-case` is prohibited and that is the reason for that exception.

In future the compilers might be more intelligent to determine proper branching based on codes, but for now we are stuck with constant values for cases. So remove the function call or use `Enum.Parse` to get the enum values and do your check. Something like this -

```
if(Enum.TryParse<TransactionTypes>(entries[index, 2], true, out TransactionTypes parsed){
    switch (parsed)
    {
       case TransactionTypes.Deposit://constant value, no issue
          rbDeposit.Checked = true;
          break;
       case TransactionTypes.Withdrawal://constant value, no issue
          rbWithdrawal.Checked = true;
          break;
       default:
          rbServiceFee.Checked = true;
          break;
    }
}
else{
    throw new Exception("Unknonw enum string");
}
```

get more details about `Enum.Parse` or `Enum.TryParse` here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8